# How to handle flask Asynchronous http request

Tags: python, flask

I am a beginner in flask. I am making several api using flask.
Below is an example of an api.

```
@app.route('/alarm', method = [POST])
def add_alarm():
   insert_task_alarmDB()
   requests.post("another server", data) 
   response = requests.post("another server", data)
   requests.post("another server", data) ...

   return response['content']
```

I would like to process the request asynchronously in the above code.
How can i do that?

..The method of official documentation of flask 2.0 does not work well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the method as async: `async def add_alarm():` and then you have to use an async library for `requests` for example [grequests](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests)